# How to get list of arguments by name and value in Python

Tags: python

How can I dynamically get the names and values of all arguments to a class method? (For debugging).

The following code works, but it would need to be repeated a few dozen times (one for each method). Is there a simpler, more Pythonic way to do this?

```
class Foo:
    def foo(self, a, b):
        myself = getattr(self, inspect.stack()[0][3])
        argnames = inspect.getfullargspec(myself).args[1:]
        d = {}
        for argname in argnames:
            d[argname] = locals()[argname]
        log.debug(d)
```

That's six lines of code for something that should be a lot simpler.

Sure, I can hardcode the debugging code separately for each method, but it seems easier to use copy/paste. Besides, it's way too easy to leave out an argument or two when hardcoding, which could make the debugging more confusing.

I would also prefer to assign local variables instead of accessing the values using a kwargs dict, because the rest of the code (not shown) could get clunky real fast, and is partially copied/pasted.

What is the simplest way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

An alternative:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

class Foo:
    def foo(self, *args):
        argnames = 'a b'.split()
        kwargs = OrderedDict(zip(argnames, args))
        log.debug(kwargs)
        for argname, argval in kwargs.items():
            locals()[argname] = argval
```

This saves one line per method, but at the expense of IDE autocompete/intellisense when calling the method.

Comment: Isn't this the same as using `**kwargs`?

Comment: @Farhan.K This `foo()` method only accepts **un**named arguments; `**kwargs` would only accept named arguments.

Answer (score 0):

As wpercy wrote, you can reduce the last three lines to a single line using a dict comprehension. The caveat is that it only works in some versions of Python. 
However, in Python 3, a dict comprehension has its own namespace and locals wouldn't work. So a workaround is to put the locals func after the `in`:

```
from itertools import repeat

class Foo:
    def foo(self, a, b):
        myname = inspect.stack()[0][3]
        argnames = inspect.getfullargspec(getattr(self, myname)).args[1:]
        args = [(x, parent[x]) for x, parent in zip(argnames, repeat(locals()))]
        log.debug('{}: {!s}'.format(myname, args))
```

This saves two lines per method.